# No root.disk while installing ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, installation, wubi

I am installing Ubuntu 12.04 on Windows Vista using Wubi, offline with pre-downloaded .iso. I executed the following command from an elevated cmd,

```
wubi.exe --dimagepath=D:\Downloads\ubuntu12.04\ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
```

The installation encounters the following error,

[image]

The contents of `wubi-12.04-rev272.log` is,

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "\lib\wubi\application.py",
>   line 58, in run   File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in
>   select_task   File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in
>   run_installer   File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line
>   197, in __ call __   File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line
>   463, in expand_diskimage   File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py",
>   line 66, in run_command Exception: Error executing command
>
> > > command=C:\Users\SuvP\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB7AC.tmp\bin\resize2fs.exe
> > >       -f D:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk 17744M
> > >       retval=1
> > >       stderr=
> > >       stdout=resize2fs 1.40.6 (09-Feb-2008) open: No such file or directory while opening D:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk

Checking the folder `D:\ubuntu\disks\` has no `root.disk`. I uninstalled `Wubi` using `Uninstall-Wubi.exe` in the `ubuntu` folder in `D:`. And I tried reinstalling, but it gives the same error.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, have you been able to solve it?

Comment: @AlexanderKuzmin Nothing yet. I had to reformat my PC in the meantime for other purposes. Haven't given it a shot again. Will update here if things work out.